# Cannot connect to compute nodes after updating ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, updates

I made the mistake to update my ubuntu server the usual way:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I updated and rebooted each node and then the main node. As a result, I cannot connect to the nodes anymore. I type `ssh compute02` and it cannot resolve host. I also went into the `/etc/hosts` file and tried to ssh to the IPs. No response.

I need a starting point on how to try to connect to the nodes remotely.